# raspbian samba cant update files

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

So I finally made some progress with Samba on my Raspberry Pi. I can now see (from Windows 7) my shared pi folder and create a text file. Yay!

However, now, if I save a file in Windows 7 and open in Raspbian, I can open it but I can't update it. Vice versa. Windows 7 says access denied and Rasbian says Can't open file to write.

How do I make it where anyone can create/update either system?

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi     pi      63 May 12 22:21 New Text Document2.txt
-rwxr--r-- 1 nobody nogroup 66 May 12 22:28 New Text Document.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `create mask = 0775` under your `[section]` and try, 
usually iirc you will be able to set a default user also in that section using `valid users=<users/groupnames>`so that it does not show `nobody` and `nogroup`

Answer (score 0):

I have a pi set up as a shared drive and use remote linux, Windows, and Mac to acces the share. All the remote systems connect to samba with the same userid (pi) password.  This means all files on the share are owned by pi/pi so all remote systems can read or write or delete them.

Here is a link to how I set up things http://lockett.altervista.org/rpi/home_nas_v2.html